# Low Latency Patch

Tags: c, linux, embedded

I am going through with the Embedded Linux(Newbie in this concept) Right now.

can any one give me a brief detail about `low latency patch` and how it is used to decrease the scheduling latency.

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Where did you head about this? Are you sure it's called 'low latency' patch and not 'real-time' patch?

Comment: *hear* about this. Sorry for typo.

Comment: i am going through with "Embedded Linux System Design And Development" this book.. and i found out this word. Yes may be it's may also called as "real-time patch", but m not sure about it

Answer (score 3):

I looked over internet and found ([here](http://people.redhat.com/bche/presentations/realtime-linux-summit08.pdf) on page 13) that so called 'low-latency' patch is a work of Andrew Morton and Ingo Molnar and was introduced in 2004 or earlier - that's too old kernel. Nowdays, it called **real-time** kernel patch. Some distros even have it in repos as `linux-rt` or `kernel-rt`. Here are some links:

- [Wiki](https://rt.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page)
- [Patches](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/rt/)
- [Article and presentation by Steven Rostedt](http://www.linux.com/news/featured-blogs/200-libby-clark/710319-intro-to-real-time-linux-for-embedded-developers)